# How to instantiate UITableViewCell with custom class in switch section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to make a object in the beginning of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to add different cells in it with switch section:

```
switch (indexPath.section) {
    case DetailControllerAddressSection: {
        NSString *address = [self addressText];
        UITableViewCell *cell;
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            if (IS_OS_7_OR_LATER) {
                cell = (CustomDetailCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AddressCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                cell.mainLabel.text = address;
                cell.detailLabel.text = [self distanceMessageForObjectData:self.objectData];
            } else {
                UniversalAddressCell *cell = (UniversalAddressCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UniversalAddressCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                cell.backgroundView = [self cellBackgroundImageView:indexPath];
                cell.mainLabel.text = address;
...
```

But in this case the cell is the `UITableViewCell` and I can't get the labels from `CustomDetailCell` class. How to solve this? The decision is simple I believe but I don't know how to solve it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this: `UITableViewCell *cell;`

Even though you cast the cell as `(CustomDetailCell *)` the storage type is still `UITableViewCell`

what you could do is:

```
switch (indexPath.section) {
case DetailControllerAddressSection: {
    NSString *address = [self addressText];
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        if (IS_OS_7_OR_LATER) {
            CustomDetailCell *detailCell = (CustomDetailCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AddressCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            detailCell.mainLabel.text = address;
            detailCell.detailLabel.text = [self distanceMessageForObjectData:self.objectData];
            cell = detailCell;

        } else {
            UniversalAddressCell *universalCell = (UniversalAddressCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UniversalAddressCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            universalCell.backgroundView = [self cellBackgroundImageView:indexPath];
            universalCell.mainLabel.text = address;
            cell = universalCell;
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'd do typecasting..

```
[(CustomDetailCell *)cell mainLabel].text = address;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have two different NIBs for two cells:

static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

```
SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case DetailControllerAddressSection:
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell1" owner:self options:nil];
        cell1 = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        // write here cell1 specific
        cell=cell1;
        break;
        case anotherCase:
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell2" owner:self options:nil];
        cell2 = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        // write here cell2 specific
        cell=cell2;

    }
}


return cell;
```